# styling Combobox in Java using Synth

Tags: java, swing, combobox, synth

Hello i want to set the background for the combobox i have to another color except from white, and during rendering when the user clicks to choose from the items inside how do i achieve that using synth??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the solution came after the fact that the combobox uses a list to display its inner things so thats what should be changed... so i added style for the list did:

  <style id="style">
    <opaque value="TRUE"/>
    <state>
      <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
      <color value="RED" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
      <color value="RED" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="SELECTED">
      <color value="RED" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
      <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
  </style>
  <bind style="style" type="region" key="List"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution came after the fact that the combobox uses a list to display its inner things so thats what should be changed... so i did:

```
<style id="style">
<opaque value="TRUE"/>

<state>
  <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
  <color value="RED" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
  <color value="RED" type="BACKGROUND"/>
</state>
<state value="SELECTED">
  <color value="RED" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
  <color value="WHITE" type="TEXT_BACKGROUND"/>
</state>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I actually found that relying on the list's  attribute alone was not enough to create the hovering effect I wanted. I tried the previous answer's code, but I was only able to change the text color( not the entire cell's color) when I hovered over an element. By  default (in "Metal"), JComboBox lists apply the highlight to an entire cell. Through trial an error, I discovered that the following combination of "ComboBox.listRenderer" styling and "List" styling enables that default effect. In my example, the list has a tan background, black text, and a gray highlight on hover.

```
<style id="ComboBoxListRenderer">
     <opaque value="true"/>
     <state>
          <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="BLACK" />
     </state>
</style>
<bind style="ComboBoxListRenderer" type="name" key="ComboBox.listRenderer"/>

<style id="ListStyle">
    <opaque value="true" />
    <insets top="0" left="0" bottom ="0" right="0" />
    <state>
     <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#E0CEB0" />
     <color type="TEXT_BACKGROUND" value="#666666" />
    </state>
```